# C++ PTHREADS - Invalid conversion void*(*)() to void*(*)(void*)

Tags: c++, casting, pthreads

I have to send the parameter "r" of type "risposta" to the function RispostaServer. The compiler gives me: `invalid conversion void*(*)() to void*(*)(void*)`

Here's the code fragment that i should correct:

```
{/*other istructions*/
risposta r;
r.mess = m1;
r.codaSC = codaSC;
pthread_create(&threads[threads_index],&attr,RispostaServer,(void*)&r);
threads_index++;
}

void* RispostaServer(void* m){
risposta* m1 = (risposta*) m;
/*other istructions*/
}
```

What should i edit ? I'm trying it by hours.

Comment: Present your [MCVE].

Comment: Seems to me your function declaration is wrong but we can only guess at the moment because you decided not to post a complete program for some reason.

Comment: You didn't provide MCV example but you need to be careful what you are passing to your thread function, `r` is local variable, when the scope ends `r` is deleted and you will get dangling pointer in body of your thread.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was late :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a stab in the dark at this, pre-[MCVE] (but please do provide one).

Does your declaration for `RispostaServer` look like this?

```
void* RispostaServer();
```

Then the only version of `RispostaServer` visible to the `pthread_create` call is one that doesn't take an argument. That matches the type complaint kicked out by the compiler.

Your later function *definition* creates a new overload of `RispostaServer` that *does* take an argument, and you'd be able to call that lower down the code, but it's too late for the `pthread_create` call by then.

The declaration should match the definition:

```
// Entrypoint for Risposta worker thread.
// Argument must be a risposta*, cast to `void*`.
void* RispostaServer(void* m);
```

By the way, your thread will be broken because you're passing in a pointer to a local variable that immediately goes out of scope, so add the following comment to the above:

```
// The risposta it points to must exist for the lifetime
// of the thread.
```

…and you really ought to be using `std::thread` rather than the C API of a platform-specific library.